# What is the difference between bpy.context.object and bpy.context.active_object?

Tags: python

I recently came across [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46178/mesh-obj-data-error-when-no-object-is-present/46179#46179) question, which has an interesting detail in the accepted answer:

> Also be aware that sometimes you should be checking for
>   `context.active_object` rather than just `context.object`.

I have wondered a few times already, and also searched the API docs, but could not find a clear answer on it: What is the difference between the two? Up until now, I had always thought they would yield exactly the same thing, but the given answer indicates that there are situations in which the content can differ.

Comment: I *think* (not certain) they will differ in the following scenario:
if you execute bpy.ops.mesh.separate() on an active object mesh in edit mode, then context.object will equal the newly separated object, not the active object currently in edit mode.